# Instana monitoring shows every msmq calls as erroneous

Tags: instana

We are testing instana apm tool, and one of our server host a msmq application. Instana reports every calls as erroneous and gives no error message.

It states as:

```
 Erroneous call without error message
```

What does it mean? I found some documents but couldn't understand:

```
Instana automatically collect logs with level WARN and ERROR (and equivalent, depending on the logging framework). In the image above, a call is erroneous and has one error log associated with it. However, in general a call might be erroneous without having error logs associated with it, and vice-versa.
```

If there is no error message or error code, how instana determines these calls as Erroneous?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instana instruments frameworks and libraries, such as msmq, at the method level. If a method returns with an error or throws an exception, Instana will detect this and mark the method call as erroneous. This will happen independently of any configured logging framework. If a supported logging framework is configured, Instana will also collect the log message for further information.